# Django: How to identifying through which link user done social authentication?

Tags: python, django, facebook, authentication, python-social-auth

I am new to Django development environment. Please help me in how to implement scenario like following in Django application.

In my web page, there are links available for do social signup/login using **python-social-auth** module (for facebook and google).  There is two type of users are there in my system, TypeA and TypeB.

In web page there will be different links for each of the type (*like TypeA-Facebook-Login, TypeB-Facebook-Login*).

When ever a user is created through **python-social-auth** service, a `User` entry is added up, using `django.dispatch.receiver` I want to make entry to table `TypeAUser` or `TypeBUser`.

*So, how can I understand through which link user is signed-up?

I have tried like following with a extra parameter in the social-auth links, but how can I access that information later on ?

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{request.path}}&profile_type=typea">
Login with faceboook</a>
```

Below is how I written @reciver function.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User,dispatch_uid="add_user_profile")
def add_user_profile(sender,instance, **kwargs):
```

Many many thanks, for the suggestions and inputs.

Comment: How did you set-up `contrib.auth` with two versions of user models?

Comment: @khajvah : I didn't modified **contrib.auth module**, just added new models like `TypeAUser` and `TypeBUser`, which has `models.OneToOneField('auth.User',primary_key=True)` as one user field.

Comment: I don't think, it's a good solution. I would suggest you to create a new table `UserTypes` and then add a new foreign key from `auth.User` to that new table.

Comment: Or an easier solution would be to use built-in `UserGroups`. I.e. have two groups "A" and "B" and then give each user either group A or group B

Comment: @khajvah but how I am supposed to get the information regarding which type of user signup is happened?

Comment: I am not sure how `python-social-auth` works. I am guessing, it does user creation/authentication automatically. If it does, you will need to go deeper into the plugin itself. I was just pointing out a greater problem that you have.

Comment: @khajvah Thank for suggesting that, I will update the structure. Let me know if you have anymore information regarding `python-social-auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be I myself figured out to implement this by `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` concept based on the following documentation [reference](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html).

following is the modifications I have done: 
Added `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` into `setting.py` with custom a pipeline

```
# social authentication pipeline
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
# custom pipeline
    'user_profile.pipeline.create_user_profile'
)
```

Also added `FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION` in `settings.py`, as follows

```
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['profile_type']
```

Then in `user_profile.pipeline.py`, defined function `create_user_profile` as follows:

```
def create_user_profile(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    print(strategy.session_get('profile_type'))
```

Now from strategy object I can access the custom value to create different type of user profile. 
[Link of reference](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html)

On the main link in which user clicks, added an extra argument at the end of url as follows:

```
http://domain.name.com/signupurl?profile_type=type1
http://domain.name.com/signupurl?profile_type=type2
```